# How to `look behind` regex in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am confused why in the following examples `#2` does not work and `#3` works.

```
 #1. get `o` if immediately preceded by J
"Jones Bond".scan(/(?<=J)o/) #=> o

 #2. get `o` if preceded by J anywhere. Since `J` occurs once I am using `+`
"James Bond".scan(/(?<=J)+o/) #=> []  empty

 #3. get `o` if preceded by J anywhere zero or more times by using `*`
"James Bond".scan(/(?<=J)*o/) #=> o
```

I translate `lookbehind` as `left-to-right` and `lookahead` as `right-to-left` to remember easily. Is it correct?

Comment: Huh, you can use a quantifier with lookarounds in Ruby? That gives an error in other languages I know.

Comment: I think you should change #2 and #3 from `+` to `.+` and `*` to `.*` respectively. I'm not sure about Ruby but most flavors of regex expect to have a fixed length when lookbehind is used. Better use lookahead instead!

Comment: More information about lookbehind length limitations in various languages: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind. (Though its Ruby information is for 1.8; Ruby 1.9 has [a more capable regex engine](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/).)

Answer (score 1):

The second example doesn't work cause you have to use a fixed size string when you lookbehind. You can do instead:

```
puts "James Bond".scan(/(J.*)(o)/)[0][1]
```

`J.*` - means  'J' followed by any number of characters - which takes the array of the results ([0]) and returns the second group ([1])

As for #3, ,since you want to find 'o' if preceded by 'J' zero or more times, you don't have to use lookbehind at all, just search for 'o':

```
"James Bond".scan(/(o)/)
```